# missing fields in web3 getTransaction

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I use web3 to get a transaction (Ropsten testnet):

```
web3.eth.getTransaction("0xea73781d8cb2dcd73ab5c7e863a2c3e2e94f99b92e4e2b9f9316be38f151ef3b")
```

I get the following fields: blockHash, blockNumber, from, gas, gasPrice, hash, input

There are missing fields if I compare to etherscan:
    https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xea73781d8cb2dcd73ab5c7e863a2c3e2e94f99b92e4e2b9f9316be38f151ef3b

How do I access to the other fields: "Gas Used By Txn", "Gas Price" (at the tx time), "Nonce" and, more specifically, the field "To" ?

Comment: Can you print the full output you're seeing? I'm not sure why you would be missing nonce, but you should also see fields like r, s, and v.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Nonce` is inside the TX, so you can retrieve it with:

```
web3.eth.getTransaction("0xea73781d8cb2dcd73ab5c7e863a2c3e2e94f99b92e4e2b9f9316be38f151ef3b")
```

0xea73781d8cb2dcd73ab5c7e863a2c3e2e94f99b92e4e2b9f9316be38f151ef3b is a contract creation TX, so it contains a void `to` field. Etherescan shows insert in the *To* field of the web page the contract address created by the TX. That address, as all others *post mining* TX attributes, can be retrieved from the TX receipt:

```
web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt("0xea73781d8cb2dcd73ab5c7e863a2c3e2e94f99b92e4e2b9f9316be38f151ef3b");
```

The actual cost of the TX is the `gas price` (found in the TX) multiplied for `gas used` (found in the receipt).

Answer (score 2):

When you send a transaction that creates a contract, the "to" field is empty. A contract is created at an address based on the sending address and the nonce.

For the rest, the fields are included. See this production example:

```
> eth.getTransaction("0x47d11e7b517a958974e1ff3e0b61598d702b710ac46a2075539b4477e41b4c63")
{
  blockHash: "0x1dd217b445ad9c4ca4627d30922dd7f672259a5b6c3416ebf92279b1ac6b6b85",
  blockNumber: 4203219,
  from: "0xafb92fd4a283ec760121e0947adb96ed7d2bf4b1",
  gas: 52385,
  gasPrice: 60000000000,
  hash: "0x47d11e7b517a958974e1ff3e0b61598d702b710ac46a2075539b4477e41b4c63",
  input: "0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000008809f960bb6dada4ac6a853d7bb47c63aae1c05200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002fa7360c0",
  nonce: 14,
  r: "0xd3fc2856cbf9a5b8469ec1216a57c8fbb0db15a08ba45c0c005c171cd5addef7",
  s: "0x69b715b3e668aa6b5c019b6191f16506692ee79c47cef713a4f4633f718bd0eb",
  to: "0xd4fa1460f537bb9085d22c7bccb5dd450ef28e3a",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0x25",
  value: 0
}
> eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x47d11e7b517a958974e1ff3e0b61598d702b710ac46a2075539b4477e41b4c63")
{
  blockHash: "0x1dd217b445ad9c4ca4627d30922dd7f672259a5b6c3416ebf92279b1ac6b6b85",
  blockNumber: 4203219,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 37385,
  from: "0xafb92fd4a283ec760121e0947adb96ed7d2bf4b1",
  gasUsed: 37385,
  logs: [{
      address: "0xd4fa1460f537bb9085d22c7bccb5dd450ef28e3a",
      blockHash: "0x1dd217b445ad9c4ca4627d30922dd7f672259a5b6c3416ebf92279b1ac6b6b85",
      blockNumber: 4203219,
      data: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002fa7360c0",
      logIndex: 0,
      removed: false,
      topics: ["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef", "0x000000000000000000000000afb92fd4a283ec760121e0947adb96ed7d2bf4b1", "0x0000000000000000000000008809f960bb6dada4ac6a853d7bb47c63aae1c052"],
      transactionHash: "0x47d11e7b517a958974e1ff3e0b61598d702b710ac46a2075539b4477e41b4c63",
      transactionIndex: 0
  }],
  logsBloom: "0x00000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000040001000000000000000800000000000080000000000000000000000018000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  root: "0xef7399bf8b2a9a1bddec13ad990afc3975a45209cf96663f3d98cb1d87957637",
  to: "0xd4fa1460f537bb9085d22c7bccb5dd450ef28e3a",
  transactionHash: "0x47d11e7b517a958974e1ff3e0b61598d702b710ac46a2075539b4477e41b4c63",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

Fields:

- "Gas Price": see `gasPrice`
- "Nonce": see `nonce`
- "Gas Used By Txn": see `gasUsed` in the receipt

There is no way to see the dollar price of ether (now or in the past) by inspecting the transaction.

Comment: Please note that "gas" attribute is the gas attached by the sender during the TX creation, it's not the gas actually consumed by the TX.